# UMA frame buffer option absent in bios (ideapad s145 ryzen 3 3200U)

Tags: windows, memory, bios, integrated-graphics

**THE PROBLEM**

I have an Ideapad S145 ryzen 3 3200U with Vega 3 Graphics (2GB integrated). Apparently, that 2GB VRAM is being used from my 8 GB RAM (I got 4 GB additionally added). This makes my usable RAM 5.88 GB.

**WHAT I WANT**

I want that only 512MB of VRAM be used from my 8 GB of RAM.

**WHAT I TRIED**

1. I googled on how can I reduce the allocated 2GB RAM for graphics and came across "UMA frame buffer" option in bios. However, the default bios even after being flashed to most recent version does not offer "UMA frame buffer" option.
2. Navigated to run -> msconfig -> boot -> (select your operating system) -> advanced options -> (now change maximum memory). This did not work.
3. Reduced the paging size. This did not work.

**WHAT I ENCOUNTERED AND THOUGHT**

1. Saw some people saying in the Lenovo support forums to contact lenovo support team, let them know about this and hope that they add this feature in bios in subsequent release. This makes you dependent on luck. Hence, practically of no value atleast at this point.
2. I was open to using a different manufacturer's bios that would offer "UMA frame buffer". However, this approach is very risky and can brick my device.

**I'm in search of community expertise. Please help!
Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you will not be able to change the memory allocation.

The general principle is that graphics hardware can reserve some of your computer's memory (RAM) for its own use, and when this happens, Windows detects it and reports that portion of your RAM as "hardware reserved".

The Frame Buffer setting you have seen elsewhere is only one example of how graphics hardware does this. It may appear in BIOS under other names than Frame Buffer but the principle is the same.

However, in the case of the Vega 3 it is a fixed limitation. There is no setting to prevent it from reserving your RAM or changing the amount of RAM reserved. Here is [another conversation about it](https://www.reddit.com/r/AMDHelp/comments/el0pyz/is_there_a_way_to_change_the_video_memory/).